# How to parse a text removing a char

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's start with that i have a txtProbe(textbox) and there i have 12-34-56-78-90. I want to parse them in different labels or textboxes ... For now just in one textbox - txtParse. I tried with that code - I'm removing the "-" and then tried to display them but nothing happens:

```
{
        char[] delemiterChars = { '-' };
        string text = txtProbe.Text;
        string[] words = text.Split(delemiterChars);
        txtParse.Text = text;
        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            txtParse.Text = s;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I want to set the received information in different labels:
12-label1
34-label2
56-label3
78-label4
90-label5

Comment: It doesn't look like nothing should happen; it looks like the textbox should have the last value, since you overwrite the value of the textbox every time.

Comment: is this ***web forms*** or ***windows forms***?

Comment: @NikolaObretenov Will there always be five labels or more? Are you creating them dynamically? No heart feelings but with this much people involved in helping you if you could post your questions better you would certainly get appropriate answers.

Comment: It will be of that how many **-**-**.... i have ... for now they are 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific sample it seems that you could just replace `'-'` by `' '`.

```
txtParse.Text = txtProbe.Text.Replace('-', ' ');
```

But in order to join an array of strings using a white space separator, you could use this

```
txtParse.Text = string.Join(" ", words);
```

Your logic is not appropiated for the task you're trying to acheive but just for learning purposes I'll write the correct version of your snippet

```
string separator = string.Empty; // starts empty so doesn't apply for first element
foreach (string s in words)
{
    txtParse.Text += separator + s; // You need to use += operator to append content
    separator = " "; // from second element will append " "
}
```

**EDIT**

This is for the case of using different labels

```
Label[] labelList = new Label[] {label1, label2, label3, label4, label5};
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{ 
    labelList[i].Text = words[i];
}
```

Comment: it says that: Index was outside the bounds of the array. 
I type your code + the fixed one from the question.

Comment: @NikolaObretenov: will the text to split always 5 elements?

Comment: It will split mostly on 5 (now i try with 5 elements)

Comment: @Nikola Obreteno: Could you debug and tell me on which element this code fails?

Comment: element: labelList[i].Text = words[i];
type: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: I can't understand why ... i have only 5 elements, and when i start the program it takes just 5 elements and the last label is empty

Comment: actually it takes some kind of empty space... i was cleaned label's text, now i tried to put some kind of text before start and when i start the program it cleans the text ...

Comment: @NikolaObretenov: I'm kind of lost :( If you split `12-34-56-78-90` by `-` you should have 5 elements and not 6

Comment: that is what i think too... I don't know what is happening ... it puts me 12 34 56 78 90 in 5 labels and in the sixth label it clears my label's text that i typed from properties ...

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `String.Replace`:

```
txtParse.Text = txtProbe.Text.Replace("-", " ");
```

Comment: I think that's missing the point. He wants each part in a different label or text box.

Comment: @MarkByers That should be easy enough to change as needed though.

Comment: Yes, obviously it's very easy, but the OP doesn't know how to do it and that's what his (poorly explained) question is trying to ask.

Comment: Yes i want to set all the results in different labels 
12- labelx1
34- labelx2
56 - labelx3

Comment: @NikolaObretenov: I think you need to make your question more clear. Almost no-one understands what you are trying to do. The code you posted is misleading people.

Comment: What is confusing here ... i have 
12-34-56-78-90
and want to place the results (12, 34, 56, 78, 90) in different labels. I want each of label.text to earn the value of each result.

Comment: @NikolaObretenov: The confusing thing is the way you have written your question. You need to make it much more clear. Pretend you are talking to children that only understand simple sentences and see if you can explain to them what you are trying to do. Your comments are *very* clear. However your question is not at all clear. And it's the question that is the most important. Remember that not everyone is going to read all the comments. You need to get your point across in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The following 'll do the trick more "semantically":

```
var parsed = text.Replace("-", " ");
```

*You might be changing the value too early in the `Page Life Cycle` (in the case of Web Forms), with regards to why you're not seeing the parsed value in the server control.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Join` to join collection of strings as you want. In your case:

```
txtParse.Text = String.Join(" ", words);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delimiter character directly in .split('-') to return an array of strings representing that data you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you keep assigning `s` to the `Text` property. The end result will be the last `s` in your array.

You can use `TextBox.AppendText()` instead.

```
    char[] delemiterChars = { '-' };
    string text = txtProbe.Text;
    string[] words = text.Split(delemiterChars);
    txtParse.Text = text;
    foreach (string s in words)
    {
        txtParse.AppendText(s + " ");
    }
```

Comment: That worked instead of that i want to set them now in labels ... as i edited my question :|

Comment: @NikolaObretenov you could add your `Label` controls to an array and do a for loop to set the `Text` property of each array. However, this is really a different question than what you originally asked. You might consider posting a new question to cover that.

Comment: So i need to add a neew question ... Roger that. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

You can just put `txtParse.Text = txtProbe.Text.Replace('-', " ");`

Or by modifying your code:

```
char[] delemiterChars = { '-' };
string text = txtProbe.Text;
string[] words = text.Split(delemiterChars,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string s in words)
{
        txtParse.Text += " " + s;
}
```